# Idea of memory reservation

Tags: linux, windows, unix, operating-system

Could someone explain me what is the idea behind reserving memory in operation systems? Why do we need "reserved" state at all? Would it be enough to have "free" and "commited"?

Reservation does not eliminate the probability of fault: attempt to commit reserved memory still can fail if the lack of resources. So, it does not guarantee anything.

If this question requires too much background then I will appreciate references to good literature explaining this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It guarantees that the address space will be available.  In most cases the programmer does not need to worry about that, and can use ordinary memory allocation functions from the runtime library or the Windows heap functions.  Typically, though, those functions will themselves use memory reservations under the hood for reasons of efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for response! What do you mean by "address space will be available"? Each process deals with virtual memory and can seize any space that it isn't using already, right?
(I am trying to figure out why do we need two steps process: reserve and then commit.)

Comment: Suppose the programmer allocates two heaps using the Windows heap functions.  If the first heap didn't reserve the address space, the second heap might wind up being allocated immediately above the first one in virtual memory, making it impossible to expand the first one while keeping its address space contiguous.